# Getstream api not returning channel name

Tags: reactjs, getstream-io, getstream-chat

I need to get channel name from GetStream channel object. I know for sure it is possible in react for mobiles where you call channel.data.name property. But I cannot find anywhere this property in GetStream channel object for react web app. The property data contains only messages and members. Does anyone know how to get that channel name?

Answer (score 0):

`name` is a custom property on channel.

If you add it, it will be returned on the response. Otherwise, it will be missing.

Custom properties are flattened to the top level so `channel.name` is the way to access it.

Comment: Yes i know but this problem is only for  one user in web app for others everything is working fine for me.

Comment: And i am also adding name while creating channel

Comment: Then, it's an issue for support to check. I would suggest contacting them so that data could be checked.

Comment: Thanks a lot , i'll request to check my data